# why is Angular $http service callback ignored?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my Angular app, I have the following code that calls an API with success and error callback functions

```
    $http.post('/analytics/generateToken', {}).then(
      function (data) {
        console.log("Success");
      },
      function (data) {
        console.log("Error");
      }
    );
```

The success callback is invoked when the API call returns a HTTP 200 status, but neither callback is invoked when the API call returns a HTTP 403 (forbidden) error status. Why is the error callback not invoked in this case?

Comment: Do you have any http `Interceptors` set up that might be blocking your response?

Answer (score 3):

It is working for me on Chrome Version 44.0.2403.52 beta (64-bit);

Make sure that you have not set an **Interceptor** that avoid the error callback to be executed.

A **Interceptor** should return a **Promise rejection** as pointed in the Angular documentation, if it does not return it, the **error callback** is not going to be executed.**

```
 'responseError': function(rejection) {
      if (canRecover(rejection)) {
          return responseOrNewPromise;
          //in this case the error callback is not executed
      }

      return $q.reject(rejection);
  }
```

Also you can consider to use the `.catch()` instead of the second argument in order to follow the Promise standard. That method is executed when the Promise is rejected or throw an error (`$http.post` return a Promise) ;

```
$http.post('/analytics/generateToken', {}).then(
    function (result) {
         console.log("Success");
     },
).catch(
    function(error) {
       console.log("error");    
    }
);
```